# Matlab: triangulate graph of a function

Tags: matlab, triangulation

I would like to eventually use the function `point2trimesh()` on the MathWorks File Exchange to measure the distance between points in R^3 and the graphs of functions, say for example `f:(x,y) -> x^2+y^2 for x^2+y^2 <= 1`, i.e. the geometric set `{(x,y,z) in R^3: x^2+y^2 <= 1, z=x^2+y^2)}`.
`point2trimesh()` requires a triangulation as input, which, after spending an hour experimenting with `delaunayTriangulation()`, I have not been able to generate for this case. Could someone point me in the right direction?